# Question about conditions of vps host provide

Tags: hosting, vps, linux

Looking into buying a VPS from a company. In their terms of service it says:

> User may not: a) Use 25% or more of
>   system resources for longer then 90
>   seconds. There are numerous activities
>   that could cause such problems; these
>   include: CGI scripts, FTP, PHP, HTTP,
>   etc.

So basically your only allowed to use a 1/4 of what your paying for? Anyone know if this is a standard restriction for most hosting providers? Seems a bit ridiculous but i don't know whats normal in the server world. And the weird thing is they only sell xen servers so why can't i use my allotted resources as no-one else can. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is referring to total CPU, but I'd stay away from that as is odd for a vps.

Comment: I have seen this in other ToSs, especially for the very low cost providers. That way, they can sell more VPS per physical machine, making the VPS more affordable.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty odd for a hosting company. I'd stay away from them. Try burst.net for good VPS's. The folk at Linode are also very reputable.

Comment: They also say you can't b) Run stand-alone, unattended server-side processes at any point in time on the server. This includes any and all daemons, such as IRCD.

Comment: Thing is they are in a country where i want it to be...

Comment: Just find another host, that's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

If they're actually using Xen, they shouldn't need any ToS restrictions as the Xen hypervisor should do all the restricting.  That's supposed to be one of the major benefits of Xen VPSs—you have your allotment of resources and it's actually your resources and when you bump up against them, it's like bumping up against the limits of a physical machine.  Also, if as you said in the comments on another answer, the ToS say you cannot run any daemons at all, it's not much of a VPS at all.